# ERROR at line 1: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to create an oracle database. After writing the following code and run it in the Oracle 11g, it's giving me an error saying as line 1 invalid character!

```
SPOOL output.log;
DROP TABLE DrinkRecord CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
/*Creates the Table */
CREATE TABLE DrinkRecord 
(
    ID  NUMBER(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DrinkType   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DrinkName   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    DrinkBenefit    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
COMMIT;
/*Begin Inserting Values into the table*/
INSERT INTO DrinkRecord (ID, DrinkType, DrinkName, DrinkBenefit) VALUES (1,’Fluid’,’Water’,’life’);
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO DrinkRecord (ID, DrinkType, DrinkName, DrinkBenefit) VALUES (2,’Liquid’,’Milk’,’Strengthen bon.’);
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO DrinkRecord (ID, DrinkType, DrinkName, DrinkBenefit) VALUES (3,’Fluid’,’Ginger Ale’,’Prevent discomfort.’);
COMMIT;
INSERT INTO DrinkRecord (ID, DrinkType, DrinkName, DrinkBenefit) VALUES (4,’Fluid’,’Fish Oil’,’vitamins.’);
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM DrinkRecord;
COMMIT;
SPOOL OFF;
```

Terminal Out put when I run the code:

[image: Terminal Out put when I run the code:]

Comment: So, if your question is about the INVALID CHARACTER error, why does the title talk about the other, TABLE OR VIEW DOES NOT EXIST, error? Is it too difficult to write a title that reflects the actual content of your question?

Comment: Don't use MS word or rich text editors  to construct your sql scripts.Use simple text editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `’` instead of `'`.

Comment: @moh - That is: you are using a "calligraphic" single-quote, instead of a straight single quote (the single quote from your keyboard). That is not allowed by Oracle syntax. You will have to change your INSERT statements to use "standard", simple single-quote characters.

Comment: @mathguy thanks for the tip! Actually, I was keep correcting that but after I saved it and run, still the error exists. Right not: I just corrected and simply copy the code and past it to my terminal and it's working with out calling it from FileZilla.

Comment: @MohK - I don't know what FileZilla is. There was no mention of it in your post. If the error is caused by FileZilla and not by Oracle, and you have follow-up questions, you will need to open a new thread, explain what is happening (error from FileZilla but not when you paste directly in the terminal), and tag the question with FileZilla. Oracle specialists may not know how to help you with THAT kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

Alas, Oracle doesn't have `drop table if exists` or `create or replace table`.  Here is one simple method:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE DrinkRecord CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;  -- this just ignores all errors
END;

CREATE TABLE DrinkRecord . . .
```

Comment: The title of the question is misleading - the OP is rather asking about a different question in the body (not the "table does not exist" error, but a different one about an invalid character).

Comment: Also - there is no need to "fix" the "table or view does not exist" error. The error message is thrown, but then the script moves on: it creates the table, it inserts the rows, etc. There is absolutely no need for the code you proposed (it is correct of course, just not necessary).

Comment: @mathguy the code is **not correct** of course, only thing that can be silently ignored is `ORA-00942`. `WHEN OTHERS` can lead to a big surprise e.g. when the tablespace is offline....

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - You are right; what I meant was "syntactically correct" - and it does allow the script to continue if the table doesn't exist, but so does just keeping the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: @mathguy my point was, you should stop if you fail to `drop` the table.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - I see what you mean, but then you should object to something else (and then I would 100% agree with you): Such SQL scripts that allow people to create "databases" should never begin with DROP TABLE (.....).  Even if there was a DROP TABLE IF EXISTS or a CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE statement. Why would a SQL script be allowed to drop tables that exist in the schema already, and that may serve legitimate purposes? A script like that should begin with creating a new, empty schema, and not have any DROP TABLE statements at the top.